# Facebook Unity SDK 5.0.3 beta - FB.API giving FileNotFoundException on Android (works fine with previous version)

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

```
FB.API("me?fields=id,age_range,gender,devices,first_name,locale,birthday,location,email", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, GetMyInfoCallback);

02-11 01:44:00.817: E/Unity(8752): java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,age_range,gender,devices,first_name,locale,birthday,location,email&access_token=&
```

That same code works on the previous FB SDK.

I'm using Unity 4.3.4.

Comment: It looks like the access token is missing.  Is there anything in `FB.AccessToken`?  Could you try logging out and back into the app?

Comment: Sorry, I already reverted back to the old version and didn't snapshot my changes to 5.0.3. I'll try again when a new version comes out.